# How can I create a link to the index of a nested resource using the brackets notation for `url_for`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say I have the following routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :sweets
end
```

If I want to show a sweet in a link, I can use brackets and Rails will automatically call the method `url_for` in my place. So, this works:

```
link_to "See this sweet", [@user, @sweet]
```

**Question:** Is there a way to specify the route for `/users/:user_id/sweets` using this brackets notation?

Basically I want to discover what should I put in the place of `thingN` in this line:

```
link_to "See this sweet", [thing1, thing2, thing3]
```

To generate the `/users/:user_id/sweets` URL.

Comment: Do `rake routes` in your terminal; you should see the URL path helper in the left column for your routes (also further described in the links Coenwulf posted).

Comment: @Teeg Note that I don't want to use the url helper (like `user_sweets_url(@user)`) - the question is if I can achieve the same using the brackets notation!

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand. You mean you want to know, as an example whether the order should be `[@user, @sweet]` or `[@sweet, @user]`?

Comment: @Teeg The `[@user, @sweet]` will route me to the show action, with the URL `/users/:user_id/sweets/:id`. I'm asking if it is possible to route to `/users/:user_id/sweets`, that is, the index action from sweets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update I think what you want can be achieved by

```
link_to "See this sweet", [@user, "sweets"]
```

That syntax should be equivalent to

```
link_to "See this sweet", user_sweets_path(@user)
```

Comment: And yet, I think I failed badly in explain what I need. Edited my question, please take a look again

Comment: I was attempting to give a possible place fontanus could look for information about how to do what was desired, but also was pointing out the missing information that might help give a more precise answer. Fontanus has now provided additional detail that I think clarifies that what I suggested wasn't appropriate, so I've updated my answer to address what I now believe the question to be.

Answer (score 0):

Use the resource keyword inside the route

```
resources :users do
  get 'sweets' => 'controller#action', :as => :collection
end
```

It produces a singleton. then use `rake routes` to find the path string.
It should produce what you want.

Comment: rake routes returns a line like this for the index action: `user_sweets GET /users/:user_id/sweets(.:format) sweets#index`. With it, I know that I can use `link_to "meh", user_sweets_path(@user)`. However, it don't explain me how to use the brackets notation, that is, something like `link_to "meh", [:sweet_index, @user]`

Comment: @fotanus there is no need for. otherwise you'll get a url like `/users/:user_id/sweets/:id`

Comment: With `[@user, @sweet]` I got `/users/:user_id/sweets/:id`. With `[:edit, @user]` I got `/users/:id/edit`. How can I have `/users/:user_id/sweets`? This is the question.

Comment: try the last changed. now i got your need